# i have probleme decode JSON

Tags: php, json, decode

can corect for my this code i have try many times but i d'ont know where is the problem thanks for help.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://fr.dofus.dofapi.fr/equipments/13644");

$test2 = json_decode($data, true);

//var_dump("<pre>", $test2['statistics'], "</pre>");

print_r($test2['statistics']['Vitalité']['max']);

print_r($test2['statistics']['Chance']['max']);

print_r($test2['statistics']['Agilité']['max']);

print_r($test2['name']);
?>
```

Comment: weird, satistics is an array, so `$test2['statistics'][0]['Vitalité']['max']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set wrong key for variable. Right code:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://fr.dofus.dofapi.fr/equipments/13644");

$test2 = json_decode($data, true);

//var_dump("<pre>", $test2['statistics'], "</pre>");

print_r($test2['statistics'][0]['Vitalité']['max']);

print_r($test2['statistics'][1]['Chance']['max']);

print_r($test2['statistics'][2]['Agilité']['max']);

print_r($test2['name']);
```